# Android project in "Titanium Studio"

Tags: android

Can we able to start an Android project in "Titanium Studio". I am using the free version of this software. If Titanium Studio is good for Android development what are the main points. How to run the application.

Comment: Honestly heard only about Eclipse and IntelliJ Idea for Android Dev.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can start an Android project in the free version of Titanium Studio. You can also start an iOS project.

When you develop in Titanium, your code is in JavaScript and you use special Titanium functions and objects to access the Android or iOS device. Some advantages are that if you know JavaScript you can code for Android and iOS without having to learn Java or objective-C and most of your code will be reusable if you want to later deploy your app on iOS. Some disadvantages are that there are bugs in Titanium that make some functions behave differently in Android and iOS. Also, if smart phones were to add a new device function you won't be able to access it until Titanium added that function. You give up some control for easier multiplatform deployment.

Titanium's Quick Start guide will show you what you need to do to setup your computer for Android and iOS development: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/#!/guide/Quick_Start